# Resume Activity from Fragment

Tags: android

I tried several times to invoke Resume method of MainActivity from the Fragment,
calling simply `onResume();` nothing in result.
code for resume method

```
   protected void onResume() {   
        all.clear();
        outgoing.clear();
        incoming.clear();
        getFromSdcard();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

I want to call this method from fragment.

Comment: An Activity contains a Fragment. What exactly do you need to resume it for?

Comment: I have written some logic in resume method , that's why i want to call after a event from fragment.

Comment: Post some code, so we can now what you have tried so far.

Comment: You **don't invoke** lifecycle methods, android does it

Comment: I have posted code, i want to call this method on button click in fragment.

Comment: NEVER call an activity life cycle function.  You will screw up the framework.  If you need to do the same code, put it in a function and call that function from onResume and wherever else you need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enhancing @cricket_007 response :

You can invoke *onResume* from the parent Activity, but just like you have seen, *onResume has protected access* blocking you from calling it.
There is a small visibility workaround that allows you to do it.

*1 - Implement this method on your activity*

```
public void myOnResume(){
    this.onResume();
}
```

*2 - Then on your fragment you can invoke*

```
public void myFragmentMethod(){
    // make sure to double check casts (to YourActivity) like these before invoking
    ((YourActivity) getActivity()).myOnResume();
}
```

**Conclusion and recommendation :** Even though it is not recommended that you implement it this way, it can be done like I said.

In my opinion, what you should do is :

1 - Have all the functionalities of your **onResume()** method inside a **proper method of your own** (you name it!) like :

```
 public void clearData() {   
        all.clear();
        outgoing.clear();
        incoming.clear();
        getFromSdcard();
    }
```

2 - Then you could just **separate all these functionalities from onResume()** and still have them invoked like

```
protected void onResume() {   
    super.onResume();
    clearData();
}
```

3 - Invoke it on your fragment like (previously shown)

```
public void myFragmentMethod(){
        // make sure to double check casts (to YourActivity) like these before invoking
        ((YourActivity) getActivity()).clearData();
    }
```

Let me know how it went.
Regards,

Comment: It's working perfectly, but i have other solution just create a static method in Activity and invoke simply in fragment.

Comment: Hi Piyush. Even though that works, it is strongly recommended that you do not use static methods to deal with/on the Activity Lifecycle. This is based on principles of good design of course! Static methods should be used to deal with data and perform operations that are not bound to the lifecycle. For example, you could declare a public static int getTwice(int value); because its purpose is mere computation and is not bound to anything (you just invoke the method on a number and it gives you the double of that number. simple as that). Either way, you can do it with the static method

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the Fragments `onResume()`

You can try `getActivity().onResume()`, but you really should make a method to do whatever code you need rather than explicitly call lifecycle methods.

Comment: I tried but got error "method is protected access in parent class".

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface

```
interface OnParentActivityResumed {
    fun onActivityResumed()
}
```

implement the interface in the fragment

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(), OnParentActivityResumed{
    override fun onActivityResumed() {
        //[YOUR CODE WHEN PARENT ACTIVITY RESUMED]
    }
}
```

on parent activity onResume add

```
  override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        myFragment.onActivityResumed()
    }
```